# Редактируемые ячейки таблицы

Tags: jquery

Брал пример отсюда: http://jsfiddle.net/4f0331ss/1/. После нажатия кнопки save ничего не происходит. Прошу подсказать, в чем моя ошибка.

```
$(function() {
    var inpMin = '<input class="input-mini">',
    butMin = '<button type="submit" class="save">save</button>';
    $('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {        
      var $that = $(this);
      if($that.hasClass('edited')) return false;
      $that.html($(inpMin).val($that.text())).append(butMin)
      .addClass('edited');
    });
    $('table td').on('click', '.save', function() {
      var $that = $(this);
      $that.parent('td').text($that.siblings('.input-mini').val())
      .removeClass('edited');
    });
});
```

Таблица **динамическая**, выводится через innerHTML.

Comment: а что должно происходить? у меня в примере по кнопке _save_ значение введенное показывается а поле вода и кнопка убираются

Comment: Поле ввода с кнопкой не исчезают.

Comment: а пример у вас работает?

Comment: на том сайте да, локально - увы

Comment: а вся остальная разметка и css  та же самая?

Comment: да, ошибок при подключении библиотек не возникает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32629/discussion-between-grundy-and-endless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что таблица генерируется динамически, а подписка на событие по клику кнопки

```
$('table td').on('click', '.save', function() {
```

предполагает что все ячейки уже доступны.
Для решения, нужно воспользоваться тем же подходом, что и для кликов по ячейке

```
$('table').on('click', 'td .save', function(e) {
```

Кроме того, теперь необходимо прервать всплытие события по кнопке *save* чтобы не заходить опять в обработчик клика по ячейке. для этого можно просто вернуть `false` из функции обработчика.
Конечный пример:

```js
$(function() {

  var inpMin = '<input class="input-mini">',
    butMin = '<button type="submit" class="save">save</button>';
  $('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    console.log('td click');
    var $that = $(this);
    if ($that.hasClass('edited')) return false;
    console.log('td click', 'not edited');
    $that.html($(inpMin).val($that.text())).append(butMin)
      .addClass('edited');
  });
  $('table').on('click', 'td .save', function() {
    console.log('save click');
    var $that = $(this);
    var siblings = $that.siblings('.input-mini');
    console.log('save click', 'siblings', siblings.length, 'val', siblings.val());
    $that.parent('td').text(siblings.val())
      .removeClass('edited');
    return false;

  });



  $('table').html(`<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>`)
})
```

```css
table {
    width: 50%;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
}
.input-mini {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1"></table>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! :)
Спустя долгое время снова понадобилась Ваша помощь, вероятно помните, с чем Вы помогли, если будет время, черкните ответ.)
Нужно отлавливать нажатия на две кнопки внутри одной ячейки(разные функции), как это можно реализовать? Сам пытался не раз, но не получалось, хотя кажется, что это довольно просто.
`<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default user'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></button><button type='button' class='btn btn-default delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></td>`

P.S. если нужно, могу оформить вопросом.

Comment: @endless, да, лучше отдельным вопросом, но не пойму в чем проблема? раньше добавляли обработчик на `td`, а теперь добавляйте на `button` так же